# Wix installer - service not starting - missing references?

Tags: c#, windows, service, wix

I've got a wix installer that requests input of connection string data, then installs the service. The problem is that the service fails to start after install.

Here is the relevant code for the files:

```
<File  Id="EmailQueueProcessorExe" DiskId="1" Name="$(var.EmailQueueProcessor.TargetFileName)" Vital="yes" Source="$(var.EmailQueueProcessor.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" />
<File Id="EmailQueueProcessorConfig" Name="$(var.EmailQueueProcessor.TargetFileName).config" KeyPath="no" Source="$(var.EmailQueueProcessor.TargetPath).config"/>
```

What it does on install is get part way through then bring up the classic generic message: "Service failed to start, verify you have sufficient privileges to start system services".  When I came across that message earlier, it was caused by missing references, which I then added in.

I've got verbose error logging turned on, but can't see anything odd - here are the last few lines of it on the off-chance it sheds some light:

```
MSI (s) (50:08) [16:02:05:851]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (50:08) [16:02:05:852]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated custom action server.
MSI (s) (50:50) [16:02:05:896]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=InstallServices,Description=Installing new services,Template=Service: [2])
Action 16:02:05: InstallServices. Installing new services
MSI (s) (50:50) [16:02:05:897]: Executing op: ProgressTotal(Total=1,Type=1,ByteEquivalent=1300000)
MSI (s) (50:50) [16:02:05:897]: Executing op: ServiceInstall(Name=Email Queue Processor Service,DisplayName=Email Queue Processor Service,ImagePath="C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\Email Queue\EmailQueueProcessor.exe",ServiceType=16,StartType=2,ErrorControl=32769,,Dependencies=[~],,StartName=NT AUTHORITY\LocalService,Password=**********,Description=Program to install Email Queue service,,)
InstallServices: Service: 
MSI (s) (50:50) [16:02:06:000]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=StartServices,Description=Starting services,Template=Service: [1])
Action 16:02:06: StartServices. Starting services
MSI (s) (50:50) [16:02:06:003]: Executing op: ProgressTotal(Total=1,Type=1,ByteEquivalent=1300000)
MSI (s) (50:50) [16:02:06:003]: Executing op: ServiceControl(,Name=EmailQueueProcessorService,Action=1,Wait=0,)
StartServices: Service: EmailQueueProcessorService
```

I saw somewhere that it could be down to administrator privileges, so I added the following:

```
<Property Id="MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION" Value="1" />
```

and also added to the `Package` tag

```
InstallPrivileges="elevated"
```

but without success.

Anyone a bit more experienced than me with WIX who knows how to debug this kind of thing?

**UPDATE - EVENT LOG ENTRIES**

`Product: EmailQueueProcessorInstaller -- Installation failed.`

`Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: EmailQueueProcessorInstaller. Product Version: 1.0.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: My Company. Installation success or error status: 1603.`

**UPDATE 2 - FULL LOG FILE**

Here is a link to the full log file: http://pastebin.com/FxdPZeH6

Comment: Is there anything related to your service in the Windows Event Log?

Comment: Hi Peter, good idea - a couple of things.  I'll post them as an update in the main question

Comment: The second issue about error 1603 looks interesting - although the log doesn't show anything conclusive (to me anyway)

Comment: Based on 1603, it sounds like the folder you are trying to install to has special permissions causing an access problem.

Comment: You should post more of that log, if there is some, and make sure you set all the log options. I see no error at all in that log fragment. Post the WiX source related to starting the service and if you wait="yes" because if you say wait="yes" the service must start properly and report back as a service to MSI, otherwise that will fail the install. So your service may be crashing.

Comment: @PhilDW - I've posted a link to the full log file at the bottom of the main question - thanks

Comment: Yeah cheers - after a day of banging my head against the wall!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turned out that the name of the service I was starting was different.
I had spaces in the first instance but not in the next.  So the problem was

`<ServiceInstall Name="Name Of Service"` and

`<ServiceControl Id="StartWindowsService" Name="NameOfService"`.

Ive updated now with variables.

Thanks for your suggestions, and thanks to Wix for your ever helpful error messages. :)